# Isometric embedding of Riemannian manifolds into Minkowski space

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, hyperbolic-geometry, isometry

I was wondering if there are any existence results similar to the Nash embedding theorem where a manifold with a Riemannian metric is isometrically embedded into flat Minkowski space, with metric of signature $(-,+,\ldots,+)$.  Allowing for the target space to be of Lorentzian signature certainly seems to help with negatively curved Riemannian metrics, i.e. the two dimensional hyperbolic plane has no isometric embedding in $\mathbb{R}^3$, however, it is easily embedded into Minkowski space $\mathbb{R}^{2,1}$ as a surface of constant proper time away from the origin.  The question would be given a Riemannian manifold of dimension $n$, what is the minimal dimension of Minkowski space $\mathbb{R}^{d-1,1}$ in which the surface is isometrically embeddable?

Comment: Possibly of interest: [Can every Riemannian manifold be embedded in a sphere?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1790879)

Comment: Your last question is unknown even in the case of isometric embeddings/immersions into Euclidean spaces. What do you expect as an  answer? An "explicit" integer-valued function on the set of isometry classes of all Riemannian manifolds?

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$The answer is "yes" because, as you note, hyperbolic $d$-space embeds isometrically in $\Reals^{d,1}$ as the set of future-pointing unit timelike vectors, and a [horosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horosphere) in hyperbolic space is a Euclidean $(d - 1)$-space. Offhand I don't know whether this (together with the Nash embedding theorem) is optimal.