# Does a differential-geometry-isometry map a (sub)vector space to a (sub)vector space?

Tags: differential-geometry

Given an isometric embedding of the tangent bundle $TM$ of a Riemannian manifold with [Sasaki metric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52509/riemannian-metric-of-the-tangent-bundle) into $ℝ^N$ with standard metric.
My intuition tells me that the vector spaces $T_pM$ ($p ∈ M$) are mapped to affine sub spaces of $ℝ^N$ but cannot find a rigourous proof. Can you help?

---

*Additional thoughts*:

The existence of the isometric embedding is guaranteed by the Nash embedding theorem.
It is unclear to me though how this embedding looks like (see [my other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4385392/how-to-construct-isometric-tangent-bundle-embedding)).

Here *isometry* does **not** mean that the distance function is preserved (that would be isometry in the metric space sense) but the Riemannian metric is preserved: $⟨dι_v A, dι_v B⟩_{ℝ^N} = ⟨A, B⟩_{G_s}$ for any $v ∈ TM$, $A, B ∈ T_vTM$, $ι$ is the isometric embedding.

The Sasaki metric restricted to $T_pM$ is what one would expect: the vertical part of $T_vTM$ ($v ∈ T_pM$) can be *identified* with $T_pM$ but answer my question one probably has to be very careful how to exploit this identification.

Comment: Can someone fix the second link, please? I cannot figure out my markdown error. Thanks.

Comment: The second link was apparently broken by the <sub> HTML tag.

Comment: @Arthur thanks! I thought I ruled that out but apparently not in the correct manner.
My intention was to highlight that technically the first paragraph constitutes the entire question and the rest are additional thoughts I had that might or might not be helpful.

Comment: If I understand the notation in the linked post, the Sasaki metric of a circle is a flat cylinder, and an isometric embedding of a flat cylinder in Euclidean space certainly need not map tangent lines to Euclidean lines. (Dimension $4$ is enough.) Generally, a high-codimension Riemannian embedding is flexible, so offhand the answer appears to be "no," not just in this isolated example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$Every Riemannian manifold can be [isometrically embedded in a sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1790879/can-every-riemannian-manifold-be-embedded-in-a-sphere/1791689#1791689); for a Sasaki metric the fibres map to bounded sets, which are therefore not affine.

To flesh out the comment, IIRC, a flat cylinder may be isometrically embedded into a bounded subset of Euclidean four-space by choosing a bounded, complete plane spiral $C$, such as the polar graph $r = 2 + \tanh\theta$, and mapping $S^{1} \times \Reals$ to $S^{1} \times C$ by the identity in the first factor and an arclength parametrization in the second.

**Added**: I overlooked that the linked question asks about closed (i.e., compact) Riemannian manifolds. The linked answer does not assume closedness, however. For self-containedness: If $(M, g)$ is a Riemannian manifold, there exists an isometric embedding into some Euclidean space $\Reals^{N}$ by the Nash embedding theorem. The real line embeds isometrically in a flat torus $S^{1} \times S^{1}$ (using for example the curve below from the linked post), so $\Reals^{N}$ embeds isometrically in $(S^{1} \times S^{1})^{N} \subset \Reals^{4N}$. Composing gives an isometric embedding of $(M, g)$ in a torus (which incidentally embeds isometrically in a Euclidean sphere).

In particular, a Sasaki metric embeds isometrically into a bounded subset of some Euclidean space, so its fibres do not generally map to affine subsets.

In case it's useful for posterity, these curves can be chosen real-analytically, so the resulted bounded embedding preserves whatever real smoothness is possessed by the Nash embedding.

[image: Embedding the line in a torus, wrapped]

Comment: This is counter-intuitive but that's math. I am trying to understand the calculation in the example and will come back.

Comment: These are $C^1$ isometries. The story is totally different for $C^2$ isometries. You have to decide which ones you want to work with. Most likely, you want $C^2$ or smoother.

Comment: @Deane If I'm not mistaken the constructions here are $C^{\infty}$...?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang, sorry. I glanced at your reference too quickly. But observe that the statement is for closed Riemannian manifolds only.